# Ellipse fit to a point by altering one axis

Tags: math, graphics, 2d

A graphic of this problem is here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13390614/Question2.jpg

Take an axis aligned ellipse with a fixed minor axis, and stretch the ellipse along its major axis till the ellipse's perimiter coincides with a point (A in the graphic). What is the new major axis length?

I can solve this problem when both axis are to be modified, but am stumped when only one axis is modified.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Gary

Comment: This is not programming related, at least not the way is asked

Answer (score 1):

First, let's pretend the ellipse is at the origin to simplify things.

Imagine it was a circle where the diameter is your minor axis. What would be the width of the circle along the line where y = P's y? Equivalently, what is the x of the point on the circle's diameter where y = P's y. (There are two solutions to this. Either will do, though you may need to adjust a sign later on.) You can compute this using either trig or Pythagorean theorem.

Your major axis is now minor axis * ((P's x) / x).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the help Laurence, that does seem to work.

Gary

// In code

Since the ellipse and point are axis aligned, 
the point is a vector.

Translate the point P onto a circle of minor axis
radius using the fixed minor axis length and the
Point's constant rise.

```
double y = fabs( P.y );
double x = sqrt( semiMnrAxLen * semiMnrAxLen - y * y );
// Calc the new Semi Major Axis length.
newSemiMajAxis = fabs( semiMnrAxLen * ( P.x / x ) );
```